# What is difference between "AS" and "IS" at declaring nested table type?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

So, if trying this anonymos block:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE  nums IS  TABLE OF integer;
  nnum nums;
BEGIN
  nnum := nums(1,2);
  dbms_output.put_line( nnum.COUNT );
END;
```

this works, but when here: `TYPE  nums IS  TABLE OF` I am replace  `IS` with  `AS`, oracle gives error:

`ORA-06550:  Encountered the symbol "TABLE" when expecting ...`

I see in docs, that both, "AS" and "IS"  are using at declaring nested table type.

and even, [from here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjcol.htm#ADOBJ7240) `To declare nested table types, use the CREATE TYPE ... AS TABLE OF statement`

Why get i am error in my case when use "AS"? what is difference here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AS` and `IS` are **synonymous** while creating PL/SQL objects like **functions, procedures and packages**. But, there are **not synonymous** when you declare a nested table type inside a PL/SQL block.

So, as far as you are using the keywords while creating an object type, they are synonymous. You will find the same difference when you create a **RECORD type**, where you can only use `IS` and not `AS`.

For example, you can create an **OBJECT type** using `AS`:

```
SQL> create type nums AS object
  2  (
  3   id  integer
  4  )
  5  /

Type created.

SQL>
SQL> create type nnum AS table of nums
  2  /

Type created.

SQL>
```

But the same would fail if you create a **RECORD type** or **declare it inside a PL/SQL block**.

Answer (score 3):

The `CREATE TYPE` is not equal to the type declaration in your PL/SQL block.

The [type creation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8001.htm) allows you to use `AS` or `IS`, but the [PL/SQL type declaration's](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/block_declaration.htm) syntax only recognises the `IS`[[3]](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/PLS23/ch4.htm).